# Html Agility Pack returns invalid XPath

Tags: .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML document opened in two windows, and I need the selected node to be synchronized between both windows.

Using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) I tried:

```
HtmlNode myNode = GetSomeCertainNode();

string xpath = myNode.XPath; //xpath = "/#comment[1]"

// This line throws an XPathException
var reExtract = myNode.OwnerDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

Exception message: `'/#comment[1]' has an invalid token.`

I'm wondering, I took the XPath from the node itself, which means it's a proper XPath, and I use it against the same document, why does it fail, what do I miss?

**Update**

When selecting some other nodes I get this exception instead: `Expression must evaluate to a node-set.` (`xpath` contains `/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/p[3]/strong[1]/#text[1]`).

But remember that the value is taken from the node itself, therefore it's very weird. How come it's complaining that it's invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The # character is illegal in an element name. A valid XPath expression that selects a comment would be `/comment()[1]`

Comment: So how come it was returned by the HtmlNode.XPath property?? is there any way to convert HtmlNode.XPath to valid XPaths?

Comment: @Shimmy: You would have to ask the developer of that library.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mak Toro's answer I created a workaround function:

```
private string ValidateXPath(string xpath)
{
  var index = xpath.LastIndexOf("/");
  var lastPath = xpath.Substring(index);

  if (lastPath.Contains("#"))
  {
    xpath = xpath.Substring(0, index);
    lastPath = lastPath.Replace("#", "");
    lastPath = lastPath.Replace("[", "()[");
    xpath = xpath + lastPath;
  }                                

  return xpath;
}
```

Now it works great.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I would suggest just using `xpath.Replace("#comment", "comment()");` Seems like there are a lot of things that could go wrong with your approach there.